# Unable to download Anaconda for python on Mac

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, installation, anaconda

I've been trying to download Anaconda for mac for the past hour or so. I install the downloader for Anaconda and use all the default settings. However, when I open terminal and enter conda, it says

```
zsh: command not found: conda
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: can you copy and paste the error code onto your post

Answer (score 1):

Likely you do not have the path to the executable set in your user profile.
In your .bashrc file or in .bash_profile or add this to your .zshrc file. Type this and save the file. The .zshrc file will be under your home directory (~/) and it will be hidden if you go looking for it in Finder.

```
export PATH="/home/username/miniconda/bin:$PATH"
```

Please ensure that you replace

> /home/username/miniconda

with your actual path to miniconda

Save and exit. Relaunch your terminal and you should be good to go.

If you don't know how to show hidden files in Mac, follow this:
In Terminal, paste the following:

```
defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles YES
```

Press return key. You will also need to relaunch finder. To be able to do that,
hold the 'Option/alt' key, then right-click on the Finder icon in the dock and click Relaunch.